# Microsoft Access 2013: Only first row in table is selected

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created a login form on Microsoft Access. The problem is the data of user selected is only the first row in 'Users' table. When I login as second user in 'Users' table, it shows wrong username/password. Two field related in this login form is 'Login' and 'Password'. Click on the following link for my screenshot of the codes

[screenshot of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNorJ.png)

Comment: What exactly do you expect that SetTempVar action to do? Because I'm pretty sure it's not doing anything remotely resembling that.

Comment: I don't know, I'm using templates and it's default code. Im just change the variable names.

Comment: What template is this?

Comment: Assets Web Database. The default login was only select user then click login button.

Answer (score 0):

Are you married to this design?  Because you really should be using VBA to do a login.  If you do that, it's a piece of cake:

```
Sub Login_Click()

If isnull(me.Login) or me.Login = "" then
  msgbox "Please provide a login name"
  exit sub
end if

If isnull(me.Password) or me.Password = "" then
  msgbox "Please provide a Password"
  exit sub
end if

Dim db = currentDB
Dim rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblLogin where fldLogin = '" & me.Login & "'")

If rec("fldPassword") <> me.Password then
  msgbox "Sorry, passwords don't match"
  exit sub
else
  msgbox "Successfully logged in"
end if

'**********************
'  Do whatever you want to do once a person is successfully logged in 
'**********************    

end sub
```

The above is air code, but is probably 95% correct as it stands.  Just add what you need to add once a person has successfully logged in and you're done.

Comment: Never tell a user logging in that the password was wrong. Just report "No such user/password". This prevents fishing by hostile actors as they won't know if the ID they are submitting exists or not.